# Is there a function like eval-print-last-sexp for Comint-Mode?

Tags: python, emacs, eval, elpy

Is there an equivalent function to eval-print-last-sexp for comint derived modes in emacs?

Specifically, I'm using python-mode (with elpy) and am looking for a way to send the contents of a region to the Python process and then print the results on the next line of the python script I'm working in.

Printing the results to the *Messages* buffer would be acceptable as well, however the behavior of eval-print-last-sexp would be preferred.

I'm running Emacs 25.1.1 and elpy 1.13.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on the comint-derived mode, since you would need to redirect the process output. Different modes have different methods of interacting with inferior processes. Python mode already has a function to do this, `python-shell-send-string-no-output` (other modes have similar functions, but you would need to search for them).

I'm not sure how exactly you want to define a sexp for python, but here is an example of sending the current line, with output like `eval-print-last-sexp`.

```
(defun python-eval-print-last-sexp ()
  "Print result of evaluating current line into current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((res (python-shell-send-string-no-output
              ;; modify to get a different sexp
              (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position)
                                (line-end-position))))
        (standard-output (current-buffer)))
    (when res
      (terpri)
      (princ res)
      (terpri))))
```

Comment: Excellent! `python-shell-send-string-no-output` was exactly what I needed and your function works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`elpy-shell-send-statement` from the [Emacs Python Development Environment](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy).